# Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null at forEach.after

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a very simple html page where I am loading two different html files using `ng-include` :-

```
<body ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <h3 class="panel-heading">Test</h3>
        <ng-include src="'View/Details.html'" ng-show="details" />
        <ng-include src="'View/Summary.html'" ng-show="summary" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Initially only the `details` variable is true thus it is loading `Details` view which looks like this:-

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
                <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and here is the controller for reference:-

```
.controller("testCtrl", function ($scope) {
     $scope.loadItems = function () {
          $scope.items= [
              { id: 1, name: "dummy" },
              { id: 2, name: "dummy1" },
              { id: 3, name: "dummy2" }
            ];
          }
        $scope.loadItems();
      }
```

When I load the page it is displaying the data properly but no events are getting triggered (all button click handlers are attached via `ng-click` & associated with behaviors defined in controller) so I went ahead and checked the console, it is displaying the following error:-

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null
>       at forEach.after (myUrl)
>       at Object.JQLite.(anonymous function) [as after]

I am pretty new to Angular. I saw few threads and tried to manipulate my mark-up code but no luck.

Comment: there is a typo please use `{ id: 2, name: "dummy1" },` instead `{ id: 2, name: "dummy1 },`

Comment: he is telling that you missed a ( " ) after dummy1

Comment: Please add double quotes `"` after dummy1 like above I've said

Comment: @Vineet - Ok thanks but that is not the issue in my code, it was a typo here.

Comment: First, your html is invalid. You cant <ng-include/> -- should be <ng-include></ng-include>. Also ng-if is usually better than ng-show, since it reduces amount of result html. Rest works:http://plnkr.co/edit/EmUYuHltWaXnjEC6juid?p=preview. Idk where you get that error.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov - You are absolutely correct, I have the habit of writing code in Visual Studio and it by default creates a self closing `ng-include` tag. That was the issue, please post it as answer and I will accept. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant `<ng-include/>` -- should be `<ng-include></ng-include>`. Also ng-if is usually better than ng-show, since it reduces amount of result html.

Rest works: [plnkr.co/edit/EmUYuHltWaXnjEC6juid?p=preview.](http://plnkr.co/edit/EmUYuHltWaXnjEC6juid?p=preview)