# How to do pagination for angular table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I am trying to do pagination for scope object in angularjs,for that am using jquery `data table` plugin.
But am getting `Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null` error,Table datas are also not displaying.

What is the meaning for this error?
Is anything wrong in my code?

```js
var app= angular.module('myApp',[])
app.controller('myController',function($scope){
$scope.details=[
{
'name':'aaa',
'age':'20'
},
{
'name':'aaa',
'age':'20'
},
{
'name':'aaa',
'age':'20'
},
{
'name':'aaa',
'age':'20'
},
{
'name':'aaa',
'age':'20'
},
{
'name':'aaa',
'age':'20'
},
{
'name':'aaa',
'age':'20'
},
{
'name':'aaa',
'age':'20'
}
]


$scope.init = function(){
$('#myData').dataTable();
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" ng-init="init()">
<table id="myData">
  <thead>
    <td>S.no</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Age</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in details">
      <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
      <td>{{data.name}}</td>
      <td>{{data.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Can anybody let me know what am wrong?Please correct me if am wrong.Thanks!!:-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null at forEach.after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089557/cannot-read-property-insertbefore-of-null-at-foreach-after)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for perform jquery object in controller you can create an directive [in this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714286/call-jquery-function-from-angularjs-controller)

but for pagination in table you can download [angular-table](https://github.com/samu/angular-table) and add `angular-table` module to your app.and then use angular table in bellow way

angular table in  your view :

```
    <table id="myData" at-config="config" at-table at-list="details">

      <tbody>
        <tr >
          <td at-implicit at-title='S.no'>{{$index+1}}</td>
          <td at-implicit at-attribute="name" at-title='Name'></td>
          <td at-implicit at-attribute="age" at-title='Age'></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
<at-pagination at-config="config" at-list="details"></at-pagination>
```

add config in your  controller:

```
 $scope.config = {
        itemsPerPage: 10,
        maxPages: 5,
        currentPage: 0,
        orderBy: 0,
        fillLastPage: false
    };
```

you can also use [pagination directive](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination) for your purpose

Comment: Thank you so much.I got it.But  index(i.e serial no) is not coming continuously..each page index starts from only..how to fix it?I want continuous serial number.